# .load return page fragment

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to load data from the output of a PHP called test2.php file and put it into a graph

HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="ct-chart ct-perfect-fourth"></div>
        <div id="data"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#data").load("test2.php #numbers ", function(result){
       console.log(result);
        var data = result.split(",").slice(1);
        var last_element = data[data.length - 1];

        new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', {
        labels: data,
        series: [data]
        }, {
                fullWidth: true,
                height: 650,
                chartPadding: {
                    right: 0
                }

        });

    });


});
```

The graph shows 0 for the last number and `console.log(result);` returns:

```
<div id='number'>,-0.05,-0.07,-0.07,-0.07,0.14,0.14,0.09,0.07,0.07,0.07,0.07,0.65,0.63,0.63,0.63,0.63,0.63,0.58,0.56,0.56,0.56,0.56,0.84,0.79,0.77,0.77</div>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="pokerHand[]" id="pokerHand"  multiple="multiple" />
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
            <input type="hidden" name="test" value="abc" id="test" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Wich is the output of my php file however `<div id="data"></div>` contans  `<div id='number'>[the numbers]</div>` how do i get .load to return the same content that it loads to the page

Comment: If the last one is what is sent to console you need to fix output from php. Needs to be a valid html page. `<div>` can't be outside `<html>`. Still not clear at all about your problem... the description is not understandable

Comment: @mplungjan i want .load to return,-0.05,-0.07,-0.07,-0.07,0.14,0.14,0.09,0.07,0.07,0.07,0.07,0.65,0.63,0.63,0.63,0.63,0.63,0.58,0.56,0.56,0.56,0.56,0.84,0.79,0.77,0.77

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Change `id` name to `numbers` in `test2.php` because you use `test2.php #numbers` in ajax url.

2) Use `$(this).text()` instead of `result` inside `.load()` callback function. It gives the text loaded in `id=data`, in our case it is numbers.

Comment: if you want to get numbers, use `$(this).text()` instead of `result` inside `load` callback function .because `result` will output entire page. `$(this).text()` gives the text loaded to `id=data`. In our case it is the numbers